# RRD raw data to JSON

Tags: javascript, highcharts, rrdtool, rrd

Can someone explain me how to extract the raw data from RRD to JSON, or to Highcharts data?  I need to search with the date range and convert data to Highcharts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/jbehrendt/Rrd2json ?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the docu? [rrdtool docu](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdxport.en.html)

simply run `rrdtool xport --json <more options here>`

Comment: This doesn't actually produce valid JSON. It produces an ECMAScript data format with unquoted keys and single quotes around strings instead.